# Which version to select

Tags: android

I would Like to make an Android App .I am just a Beginner .As am at the first stage I need to Know  if I make an App for 2.2 version will it work for 2.2 and  above it .?

Comment: **"if I make an App for 2.2 version will it work for 2.2 and above it .?"** : In short, yes. You won't be able to use any of the newer Android features however unless you use the support libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres multiple details you should account for.

From the official android developers site:

> Applications can use a manifest element provided by the framework API
>   —  — to describe the minimum and maximum API Levels under
>   which they are able to run, as well as the preferred API Level that
>   they are designed to support. The element offers three key attributes:

```
android:minSdkVersion — Specifies the minimum API Level on which the application is able to run. The default value is "1".
android:targetSdkVersion — Specifies the API Level on which the application is designed to run. In some cases, this allows the application to use manifest elements or behaviors defined in the target API Level, rather than being restricted to using only those defined for the minimum API Level.
android:maxSdkVersion — Specifies the maximum API Level on which the application is able to run. Important: Please read the <uses-sdk> documentation before using this attribute.
```

You can define a target SDK version, a maximum and a minimum SDK version. This means your app will run from minSDKVersion to maxSDKVersion.

You can define this in your Manifest.xml.
To know more about this attribute, and to know what are the pros and cons of your decision, check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Answer (score 1):

Each new Android version provides an additional/incremental set of features (to the API) compared to the previous version. So creating an application for 2.2 limits you in the available 'modern' functionality (as it was not yet provided/added).

If you do not require any of the functionality of Android 2.2+, then you design your application for 2.2 and it will (*most likely*) work on higher versions of Android as well.

Note that *some* of the 'modern' functionality is provided by the (backwards compatibility) [support libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) for older Android versions. So you are still able to use this functionality.